# How would I fade an icon to a lower opacity using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, css

I have these set of icons,

```
<div class="nav">
<a href="/ask" title="Ask Question"><img id="icon"
src="http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/4KZlie2ck/08-chat.png"></a>
<a href="/random" title="Random"><img class="icon1" id="icon"    
src="http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/oOFlie27f/05-shuffle.png"></a>
<a href="/archive" title="Archive"><img id="icon"
src="http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/G1Glie23v/11-clock.png"></a>
</div>
```

And when hovered I would like them to fade to a lower opacity. I don't want to have to call the images using Javascript... Is this easy enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.icon').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.4);
    }, function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to fix that HTML to use a `class` attribute. You can't have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute.

```
<div class="nav">
<a href="/ask" title="Ask Question"><img class="icon"
src="http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/4KZlie2ck/08-chat.png"></a>
<a href="/random" title="Random"><img id="icon1" class="icon"    
src="http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/oOFlie27f/05-shuffle.png"></a>
<a href="/archive" title="Archive"><img class="icon"
src="http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/G1Glie23v/11-clock.png"></a>
</div>
```

Then, use this jQuery:

```
$('img.icon').hover(
    function() {
        console.log('hello');
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 });
    },

    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 });
    }
);
```

That'll animate the icon to 50% opacity on mouse enter, and back to 100% on mouse leave.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/ATTZe/2/)

Comment: .stop should be added to both animate statements to stop the animation effect to being triggered multiple times. $(this).stop().animate({opacity: .5});

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't have multiple elements with the same `id`, so `id="icon"` should become `class="icon"`, then you can add these hover functions using jQuery:

```
$('.icon').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, .3);
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(300, 1);
});
```

Where the first number in the `fadeTo()` is the duration, and the second is the opacity, on hover and unhover respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's not working though :( Could you check it out at roseanneconner.tumblr.com. I honestly have no idea why it didn't everything is in their correctly. I made sure to change each id to class.

Comment: Nope, they all have `id="photoSmall"` still.  You can either try using that id in the `$()` selector or change them to classes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser support needs, you could use the [CSS3 opacity](http://www.zenelements.com/blog/css3-opacity/), with a :hover selector.  No jQuery needed, works great in modern browsers (Gecko, Webkit, Opera...maybe IE9, but I can't test that).

Add CSS like this:

```
img:hover{opacity:0.50;}
```